# method returning <T extends BaseClass> & Baseclass

Tags: java, generics

what is the difference between these two method signatures

1. `public <T extends BaseClass> T myMethod(String p1, String p2) {}`
2. `public BaseClass myMethod(String p1, String p2) {}`

Which one is better and what are the appropriate places where these should be used.

Alright I know generics, the reason I asked this question is that both the methods can return a extension of the baseclass and I came across a piece of code that was using the generics version, I was trying to figure out why?

Comment: You need to learn about generics.

Comment: Read the java tutorial on generics.

Comment: Your example as written is useless; the only expression convertible to `T` is `null`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The signature under 1. will save you from a downcast of the method's return value into the specific subclass of `BaseClass`. However, it is inherently type-unsafe because `T` is inferred only from the type of the expression which invokes this method. In other words, `T` is "whatever you want it to be", which clearly cannot work since the method returns an object of  a definite type.

If you had a `T`-typed *argument* to the method, or `T` was involved as a type parameter of such an argument, then this signature would make sense; this way it makes very little.